# Angularjs Bind issue

Tags: angularjs, binding

I have a simple sample code , consists of 3 variables a b and testvar, testvar is sum of a and b, I am trying to understand why the binding does not work for variable testvar when value of a changes , I have created a input with its model as a. How this can be achieved, Any help is greatly appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input  ng-model="mymodel.a"><br>
Why this value does ot change on changing input:{{ mymodel.testvar}}
<br>
mymodel.a changes on input change: {{mymodel.a}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.mymodel={};

 $scope.mymodel.a=1;
$scope.mymodel.b=2
$scope.mymodel.testvar =$scope.mymodel.a+$scope.mymodel.b;
});
</script>

<p>Test Binding.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
$scope.mymodel.testvar =$scope.mymodel.a+$scope.mymodel.b;
```

Binds `a + b` to `testvar` only one time, using the initial values of `a` and `b`.

One solution is to turn `testvar` into a function, like this:

```
// Javascript
$scope.getTestVar = function() {
    return $scope.mymodel.a+$scope.mymodel.b;
};

<!-- HTML -->
TestVar: {{getTestVar()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `mymodel.testvar` does not get updates when you change `mymodel.a` or `mymodel.b` is because when your controller is run for the first time `testvar` is evaluated to the sum of `a` and `b`'s initial values hence `testvar` is equal to 3.  So the variable `testvar` stores the literal value 3. Now when you change `a` or `b` to let's say 4 you are not re-evaluating `testvar`. `testvar` is still 3. In scenarios like this if you want to recalculate `testvar` to have to put it into a function like `mymodel.testvar = function(){ return mymodel.a + mymodel.b};` you then bind to the function call. Or in angular you can bind to the addition expression directly something like `{{mymodel.a + mymodel.b}}`

Comment: Thanks ! Neat explaination